# Access Apache VHost Domain through OpenVPN

Tags: windows, openvpn, apache2, hosts

In my company, we're using `OpenVPN` to connect to our network for remote-working

We have a local server that our employees can access (so through the VPN too), which contains a lot of local websites served by Apache VHost

The problem is, we have domain to access to those websites (i.e thewebsite.company.com) but the ones who come from the VPN can't access them because Windows don't know how to map the domain with the IP address of the concerned Apache server

The workaround I found is to declare the mapping in the `hosts` file of Windows, which works totally good, but is so not user-friendly and have to be effected in every desktops accessing through VPN

So, I wonder if there is a better method to configure that server-side so on Apache or OpenVPN ?

Comment: Let the VPN clients use your company DNS server that can resolve the domains?

Comment: I don't think my company has his own DNS server, have to ask. But how could you achieve that ? Is there a configuration ?

Comment: The ones they use on the local network; those that already resolves the correct server for the LAN users. We know they exists because you declared it's working on the LAN.

Comment: True that ! So now I should configure the DNS in OpenVPN server ?